# Force someone to make his sub classes implement an interfaces' methods

Tags: php, interface, subclass

I'm wondering how to force sub classes to implement a given interface method.

Let's say I have the following classes :

```
interface Serializable
{
    public function __toString();
}

abstract class Tag // Any HTML or XML tag or whatever like <div>, <p>, <chucknorris>, etc
{
    protected $attributes = array();

    public function __get($memberName)
    {
        return $this->attributes[$member];
    }

    public function __set($memberName, $value)
    {
        $this->attributes[$memberName] = $value;
    }

    public function __construct() { }

    public function __destruct() { }
}
```

I would like to force any sub class of "Tag" to implement the "Serializable" interface. For example, if i a "Paragraph" class, it would look this way :

```
class Paragraph extends Tag implements View
{
    public function __toString()
    {
        print '<p';
        foreach($this->attributes as $attribute => $value)
            print ' '.$attribute.'="'.$value.'"';
        print '>';

        // Displaying children if any (not handled in this code sample).

        print '</p>';
    }
}
```

How can i force a developer to make his "Paragraph" class implement the methods from the interface "Serializable"?

Thanks for taking the time to read.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Just have the abstract class implement the interface:

```
interface RequiredInterface 
{
    public function getName();
}

abstract class BaseClass implements RequiredInterface 
{

}

class MyClass extends BaseClass
{

}
```

Running this code will result in the error:

> Fatal error: Class MyClass contains 1 abstract method and must
>   therefore be declared abstract or implement the remaining methods
>   (RequiredInterface::getName)

This requires the developer to code the methods of `RequiredInterface`.

Comment: But that is only if the developers implements `RequiredInterface`. I think the question was more along the lines of, how do you force them to implement the interface, not the methods in the interface.

Comment: @sixeightzero: I see no practical outward difference between forcing a developer to code the methods of an interface through inheritance and forcing a developer to type the characters `implements RequiredInterface`. However, using inheritance and abstract classes is the better way to do this as it imposes design rules through OOP structure, rather than relying on runtime to perform the check.

Comment: Thanks for you answer. It looks like a clear solution. But my "Tag" class doesn't know how to implement to __toString method, only sub classes do. Won't it generate errors if i declare my base class "Tag" as implementing the interface but don't implement the methods ?

Comment: @Virus721: Not if `Tag` is abstract.

Comment: I tried this solution but it generates an error : Fatal error: Cannot redeclare class Serializable in C:\Program Files\wamp\www\ViewTree 2.0\view.php on line 3 - CODE: `<?php

interface Serializable
{
    public function __toString();
}

abstract class Tag implements Serializable
{
    protected $attributes = array();
}

class Paragraph extends Tag
{
    public function __toString()
    {
        // Some code
    }
}

$p = new Paragraph();
$p->id = 'TestParagraph';
$p->class = 'Title';

echo $p;

?>`

Comment: Well i think i found the problem : the Serializable interface maybe already exists in PHP ? i Changed it's name to check and it worked

Answer (score 1):

PHP code example:

```
class Foo {
  public function sneeze() { echo 'achoooo'; }
}

abstract class Bar extends Foo {
  public abstract function hiccup();
}

class Baz extends Bar {
  public function hiccup() { echo 'hiccup!'; }
}

$baz = new Baz();
$baz->sneeze();
$baz->hiccup();
```

It is possible for an abstract class to extend Serializable, as abstract classes **do not** need to be **base** classes

Comment: Thanks for your quick answer. I'm not sure to understand though. This Foo class is being used as the interface ? In my case, neither of "Serialisable" or "Tag" know how to implement __toString, only sub classes do as "Tag" represents nothing real. I'm a bit confused sorry.

Comment: Any php class that implements Serializable is serializable

Comment: `abstract class Tag implements Serializable`

Answer (score 0):

This adds a `__construct`or to your class `Paragraph` which checks to see if `Serializable` is implemented.

```
class Paragraph extends Tag implements View
{

  public function __construct(){
    if(!class_implements('Serializable')){
        throw new error; // set your error here..
    }
  }

  public function __toString()
  {
    print '<p';
    foreach($this->attributes as $attribute => $value)
        print ' '.$attribute.'="'.$value.'"';
    print '>';

    // Displaying children if any (not handled in this code sample).

    print '</p>';
  }
}
```

Comment: Why force class design rules at runtime when it can be done at parse?

Comment: Thanks. Could be handy some day, but webbiedave's answer is closer to what i'm looking for.